# Basic batched GET requests using REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, office-365, rest, batch

I'm hunting around on the web right now for some basic (preferably working) examples of making a batch of GET requests using the new `$batch` endpoint in O365 with the REST API.

I've located some good information from [Andrew Connell](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/part-2-sharepoint-rest-api-batching-exploring-batch-requests-responses-and-changesets) and [Steve Curran](https://github.com/SteveCurran/sp-rest-batch-execution) but I'm hoping someone could offer some working JavaScript to demonstrate the concepts.

**How do I make a batched REST request using JavaScript to read information from two separate lists?**

Should I immediately look at hooking into a helper library like [datajs](http://datajs.codeplex.com/documentation) or [Steve Curran's RestBatchExecutor.js](https://github.com/SteveCurran/sp-rest-batch-execution/blob/master/RestBatchExecutor.js) or is this basic enough to do using `SP.RequestExecutor` or `jQuery.ajax`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've been playing around with [REST Batching feature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn903506.aspx) recently and found [datajs library](https://datajs.codeplex.com/) supports it in a relatively convenient way.

The following example demonstrates how *make a batched REST request using JavaScript to read information from two separate lists*:

```
var jsonSPHeaders = {  
    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose", 
    "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "DataServiceVersion": "3.0" 
};

OData.request( {
    requestUri: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/$batch",
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
               "DataServiceVersion": "3.0" },
    data: { __batchRequests: [
       { requestUri: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Pages')/items", method: "GET" , headers: jsonSPHeaders },
       { requestUri: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Tasks')/items", method: "GET", headers: jsonSPHeaders }
    ]}
},
function (data, response) {
    console.log('Pages list:');
    printListItems(data.__batchResponses[0].data);
    console.log('Tasks list:');
    printListItems(data.__batchResponses[1].data);
}, 
null, 
OData.batchHandler);



function printListItems(data){
   data.results.forEach(function(item){
       console.log(item.Title); 
   });
}
```

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/8bc73080f42e1e11aa5b)

Comment: I like the API much better than trying to craft the requests and sift through the responses myself -- 82k (minified) is a little bigger than I would like for datajs but smaller than breeze at least

Answer (score 9):

I've managed to work out how to build the request manually like Andrew Connell does in his [`SpRestBatchSample` on Github](https://github.com/andrewconnell/sp-o365-rest/blob/master/SpRestBatchSample/) (which happens to be how the [MSDN example on the topic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn903506.aspx#sectionSection1) does as well), but the experience certainly leaves a lot to be desired... I think I will try doing this with [breeze](http://www.getbreezenow.com/) next...

The below uses `SP.RequestExecutor` but assumes that you're requesting data within the same site as where the code is run -- as posted it just logs the response `results` objects to the console:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("SP.RequestExecutor.js", "SP.RequestExecutor", function () {
    // create a new executor for the current web
    var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl);
    // get a new Guid for the batch using the scripthelper utility
    var batchGuid = SP.ScriptHelpers.newGuid();
    // setup an array to hold strings that will be sent as the request body
    var batchContents = new Array();

    // build first request section against List1
    var endpoint = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl
        + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List1')"
        + "/items";

    batchContents.push("--batch_" + batchGuid);
    batchContents.push("Content-Type: application/http");
    batchContents.push("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    batchContents.push("");
    batchContents.push("GET " + endpoint + " HTTP/1.1");
    batchContents.push("Accept: application/json;odata=verbose");
    batchContents.push("");

    // build second request section against List2
    var endpoint = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl
        + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List2')"
        + "/items";

    batchContents.push("--batch_" + batchGuid);
    batchContents.push("Content-Type: application/http");
    batchContents.push("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    batchContents.push("");
    batchContents.push("GET " + endpoint + " HTTP/1.1");
    batchContents.push("Accept: application/json;odata=verbose");
    batchContents.push("");

    // end the request with `--batch_batchid--`
    batchContents.push("--batch_" + batchGuid + "--");

    // join the array contents to build a single batch body string
    var batchBody = batchContents.join("\r\n");

    executor.executeAsync({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/$batch",
        method: "POST",
        body: batchBody,
        headers: {
            "X-RequestDigest": document.getElementById("__REQUESTDIGEST").value,
            "Content-Type": "multipart/mixed; boundary=batch_" + batchGuid
        },
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            var responseInLines = response.body.toString().split('\n');
            // read routine below courtesy of Andrew Connel: https://github.com/andrewconnell/sp-o365-rest/tree/master/SpRestBatchSample
            // read each line until you find JSON...
            for (var currentLine = 0; currentLine < responseInLines.length; currentLine++) {
                try {
                    // parse the JSON response...
                    var tryParseJson = JSON.parse(responseInLines[currentLine]);
                    console.log(tryParseJson.d.results);
                } catch (e) {
                    // don't do anything... just keep moving

                    // execution in this block just means we hit a 
                    // line in the response that was not valid JSON -JM
                }
            }
        },
        error: function (response) { console.log(response) }
    });
});
```

The main reason I think I will try [breeze js](http://www.getbreezenow.com/) next is because the responses are given in a mixed text/json format that is fairly ugly to parse through (hence the `try...catch` I stole and used in my `success` function...)

One thing that really tripped me up -- [in Andrew Connell's example he uses the following syntax on line 197](https://github.com/andrewconnell/sp-o365-rest/blob/master/SpRestBatchSample/Scripts/App.js):

```
batchContents.push(
    'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="changeset_' + 
    changeSetId + '"');
```

I had to remove the quotes enclosing the `boundary` section of the `Content-Type` value, otherwise I would only receive an empty response from the server to my REST request.

My request content type string wound up looking like

```
...; boundary=changeset_fcb3e12a-124f-4548-9464-b20902edab92
```

instead of

```
...; boundary="changeset_fcb3e12a..."
```

This may just have something to do with his example using `jQuery.ajax` and mine using `SP.RequestExecutor` though

I'll definitely leave the answer open for a while even though this is doing basically what I was looking for -- I think there is some room for improvement.

Answer (score 1):

For SharePoint Online and SharePoint 2016/2019 $batch Rest API is supported.
However, $batch REST API supported but implementation is very tricky, and there is very limited resource available online.

Recently I have found an easy way to implement $batch API using a few lines of code using [BatchUtils.ts](https://github.com/anomepani/sp-rest-util/blob/master/BatchUtils.ts). See below code snippet for CRUD Operation using $batch API.

**GET Operation code snippet**

```
//Prepare array of all request urls

var arr=["https://brgrp.sharepoint.com/_api/Lists/Getbytitle('PlaceHolderList')/items(212)"
, "https://brgrp.sharepoint.com/_api/Lists/Getbytitle('PlaceHolderList')/items(213)"
, "https://brgrp.sharepoint.com/_api/Lists/Getbytitle('PlaceHolderList')/items(214)"];

//Pass rootUrl and array of request as below
BatchUtils.GetBatchAll({rootUrl:"https://brgrp.sharepoint.com",
batchUrls:arr}).then(r=>console.log(r))
```

**CREATE, UPDATE and DELETE Operation Code snippet**

```
// Prepare collection of request with requestUrl and payload data.
var arr=[{
reqUrl:"https://brgrp.sharepoint.com/_api/Lists/Getbytitle('PlaceHolderList')/items(212)"
,action:"UPDATE",
data:{__metadata:{type:"SP.Data.PlaceHolderListListItem"},Title:"Update Article_1"}},
{
reqUrl:"https://brgrp.sharepoint.com/_api/Lists/Getbytitle('PlaceHolderList')/items(213)"
,action:"UPDATE",
data:{__metadata:{type:"SP.Data.PlaceHolderListListItem"},Title:"Update Article_2"}},
{
reqUrl:"https://brgrp.sharepoint.com/_api/Lists/Getbytitle('PlaceHolderList')/items(214)"
,action:"UPDATE",
data:{__metadata:{type:"SP.Data.PlaceHolderListListItem"},Title:"Update Article_3"}},
{
reqUrl:"https://brgrp.sharepoint.com/_api/Lists/Getbytitle('PlaceHolderList')/items"
,action:"ADD",
data:{__metadata:{type:"SP.Data.PlaceHolderListListItem"},Title:"Add Article_1"}}
,{
reqUrl:"https://brgrp.sharepoint.com/_api/Lists/Getbytitle('PlaceHolderList')/items(215)"
,action:"DELETE"}];

BatchUtils.PostBatchAll({rootUrl:"https://brgrp.sharepoint.com",
batchUrls:arr}).then(r=>console.log(r));
```

Reference links:

1. [SharePoint Batch API Examples](https://anomepani.github.io)
2. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sharepoint-batch-request-for-add-list-item/

Answer (score 0):

Batch jquery request that returns calendar recurrences.

```
getRecurrenceData: function(IDs){
    var guid = "batch_" + SP.ScriptHelpers.newGuid();
    var __data = ''; 
    var _data = [];
    
    $(IDs).each(function(i,e){
        __data = __data + "--" + guid + "\r\n" +
            "Content-Type: application/http\r\n" +
            "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\n" +
            "GET " + _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Conference%20Room%20Request%20Portal')/items(" + e + ")/FieldValuesAsText?$select=id,RecurrenceData HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
            "Accept: application/json;odata=verbose\r\n\r\n";
    });
    
    __data = __data + "--" + guid + "--";
    
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/$batch", async: false,method:'POST',processData:false,
        headers: {Accept: '*',"content-type": 'multipart/mixed; boundary=' + guid,"X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()},
                data: __data,
        success: function(data){
                    var dataLines = data.toString().split('\n');
                    for (var count = 0; count < dataLines.length; count++){
                        try{
                            var parsed = JSON.parse(dataLines[count]);
                            _data.push(parsed);
                        }
                        catch(e){}
                     }
        },
        error: function(e){}
    });
    return _data;
},
```