# How to Get Lookup column using lookup column using REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I have one summery custom list in which I have lookup column of detail list.

So I am retrieve all data from it using expand it. But in detail list I also have one lookup column of personal Detail list.

Now how can I get personal Detail from lookup of summery list.

Any help will highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not `$expand` any lookup column of child list. You can only `$expand` all lookup column of parent list. Let say, you are querying on **A** list and **A** has a lookup column from **B** list. **B** has a lookup column from **C** list. So if you are querying on **A** list, then you can only `$expand` all columns of **B**.

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('A')
```

You can not `$expand` any column from **C**. The reason is there is no direct relation between **A** and **C**.

## Workaround

At first get the item `Id` of **B** list, then make another REST call to **B** and $expand the columns of **C**

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('B')/items({ItemId})?$select={select column from c}&$expand=C
```

You can use [SharePoint REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sp-rest-client/ojnaikgchcnginnmkmkonmdglhjikokd) to test your query.

## Update

You can make a batch request as you have many items from **B**.

[Make batch requests with the REST APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn903506.aspx)

Comment: i know there is no way to get nested lookup column  data . i just want alternative way. you are right but i  have multiple  lookup so i have to call multiple time to get there id and then expand it. so i think this is not good way to call multiple request from mobile.

Comment: alternative way is to make another GET request that I have mentioned as workaround

Comment: yes i can achieve using your optional way but i have multiple lookup in A list then i have to get all item id from list b then from there id i have call all items to expand lookup of C.so if i have 6 item in A then i have to call 6 time in C to expand it data.

Comment: In that case you can make a batch request

Comment: can you please provide any example for batch request in REST

Comment: see this http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/166017/21421. Now you can consider to accept this answer

Comment: Also this http://sharepointfieldnotes.blogspot.com/2015/01/sharepoint-rest-api-batching-made-easy.html

Comment: but i my front end is android so i didnt have BatchRequest.

Comment: There should be some way in Java. Otherwise make multiple requests