# Sharepoint Online Rest/Api, Join multiple List

Tags: sharepoint-online, joined-view, sharepoint-rest-api

Environment: SharePoint Online

I use **Rest api** to communicate with my lists. I must now, show a list which joins 3 lists:

> List1 : ID, Title, Field1_Loockup(List2.ID)
>
> List2 : ID, Title, Field2_Loockup(List3.ID)
>
> List3 : ID, Title

I want like result :

> List1.ID | List1.Title | List2.ID | List2.Title | List3.ID |
>   List3.Title

How can I do?

Comment: Why Don't you use Content Search Webpart?

Answer (score 4):

You can try using the `expand` clause

```
http://siteurl/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('listname')/items?$select=id,title,field1_lookup/id,field1_lookup/title&$expand=field1_lookup
```

I am not sure if it's possible to expand the second level i.e `field2_lookup` but you can try

```
http://siteurl/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('listname')/items?$select=id,title,field1_lookup/id,field1_lookup/title,field1_lookup/field2_lookup/id,field1_lookup/field2_lookup/title&$expand=field1_lookup,field1_lookup/field2_lookup
```

Comment: `$expand` does not work in second level. The reason is SP does not support nested query.

Comment: Yeah I thought the same

Comment: Similar question I answered few days back http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/192432/21421

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Content search webpart which will be a huge boost to your application.

If all the list have same content type then search on the basis of that else use OR condition for the different content types.

In the display template you can easily manipulate the data to show in which ever fashion you want.