# SharePoint 2013 REST query : Expand Person field in parent list

Tags: sharepoint-addin, rest

All,
    have not seen this particular scenario mentioned after some google searches. I have a 2 lists I am trying to perform an expand on.

## Parent: Contract

**ParentFields:**

- ContractNumber (number)
- ContractEffectiveDate (date)
- ContractHolder (person with presence)

## Child: ContractItem

**ChildFields:**

- Title (string)
- ItemNumber (number)
- ContractNumberRef (lookup to Contract list)

The REST query is as follows:

```
_api/web/lists/GetByTitle(ContractItem)/items?$select=ContractNumberRef/ContractNumber,ContractNumberRef/ContractHolder&$expand=ContractNumberRef&$filter=ItemNumber eq '11111234567'
```

I can get the parent fields from the expand query, however when I try to expand the person field, it throws an error "The query to field 'ContractNumberRef/ContractHolder' is not valid. Is this possible to expand a field in the parent list (2 level expand) or is my query just bad? looking for some expert advice if this is even possible or I need to change my data design.

Answer (score 1):

Nested query or 2 level `$expand` is not possible. You can check my explanation from [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/192445/21421).

Also check REST [API Limitations-Workarounds](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/194328/21421)