# Retrieve lookup fields with REST API

Tags: custom-list, sharepoint-rest-api

All,

I like to retrieve data from two Lists. The main list is called OIE ALerts.
The secondary List is Countries. I like to get the country code for the Country field in OIE Alerts. The country code is the second list.

OIE Alerts, field Country (lookup) = "Nederland"
Countries, field LandNaam (single line) = "Nederland", LandCode (single line) = NLD

Found this example but confused how to make it work for me:

```
var urlForOrderBy = "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('OIE Alerts')/Items?" +
    "$select=ID,Title,Country,Date_of_Event,LandCode," +
    "SpPerson/Name,SpPerson/Title,SpLookup/Title,SpLookup/ID" +
    "&$expand=SpLookup,SpPerson&$orderby=Date_of_Event desc";
```

Answer (score 1):

From your explanation I understand that LandNaam and LandCode are in the same list, so this should work: `"/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('OIE Alerts')/Items?" +
"$select=ID,Title,Date_of_Event,Country/LandCode,Country/LandNaam" +
"&$expand=Country&$orderby=Date_of_Event desc";` If LandCode is also a lookup, please refer to [this explanation](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/192432/how-to-get-lookup-column-using-lookup-column-using-rest-api)

Comment: LandName and LandCode are text fields in the List Countries. Country is a lookup field in the main list.