# update multiple items, rest api, javascript

Tags: javascript, rest

I'd like to update several items on a list through the rest api, this is how I update one item:

```
    update: {
        method: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": function() {return  $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()},
            "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
            "If-Match": '*'
        },
        url: "serverRelativeURL/_api/lists/getByTitle('ListName')/items(:ID)"
    }
```

Where **":ID"** is the id of the list item

Is is possible to update multiple items, without doing this request in a loop for each item?

Answer (score 4):

You can do that using batch request. Batch request is only available in SharePoint Online & SharePoint 2016. Find some useful references.

- [Basic batched get requests using REST API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/166010/21421)
- [SharePoint REST API Batching - Understanding Batching Requests](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/part-1-sharepoint-rest-api-batching-understanding-batching-requests)

Comment: we're using 2013, but still useful, thanks

Comment: then you can go for **JSOM**. update multiple items and finally call `context.executeQuery()`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible without loop, at least based on the provided List and List Items REST API Reference (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531433.aspx).