# Sharepiont REST GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl get files from multiple folders

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

Let suppose I have the following three sharepoint Rest APIs call, I want to merge them to one call for paging and sorting.

_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/emails24/1001')/Files
_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/scaned/1001')/Files
_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/lnked/1001')/Files
Does anyone have any idea, how to achieve this.

Or any alternative way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the batch API as below:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("SP.RequestExecutor.js", "SP.RequestExecutor", function () {
    // create a new executor for the current web
    var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl);
    // get a new Guid for the batch using the scripthelper utility
    var batchGuid = SP.ScriptHelpers.newGuid();
    // setup an array to hold strings that will be sent as the request body
    var batchContents = new Array();

    // build first request section against first call
    var endpoint = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl
        + "/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/emails24/1001')/Files";

    batchContents.push("--batch_" + batchGuid);
    batchContents.push("Content-Type: application/http");
    batchContents.push("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    batchContents.push("");
    batchContents.push("GET " + endpoint + " HTTP/1.1");
    batchContents.push("Accept: application/json;odata=verbose");
    batchContents.push("");

    // build second request section against second call
    var endpoint = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl
        + "/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/scaned/1001')/Files";

    batchContents.push("--batch_" + batchGuid);
    batchContents.push("Content-Type: application/http");
    batchContents.push("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    batchContents.push("");
    batchContents.push("GET " + endpoint + " HTTP/1.1");
    batchContents.push("Accept: application/json;odata=verbose");
    batchContents.push("");

    // build second request section against third call
    var endpoint = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl
        + "/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/lnked/1001')/Files";

    batchContents.push("--batch_" + batchGuid);
    batchContents.push("Content-Type: application/http");
    batchContents.push("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    batchContents.push("");
    batchContents.push("GET " + endpoint + " HTTP/1.1");
    batchContents.push("Accept: application/json;odata=verbose");
    batchContents.push("");


    // end the request with `--batch_batchid--`
    batchContents.push("--batch_" + batchGuid + "--");

    // join the array contents to build a single batch body string
    var batchBody = batchContents.join("\r\n");

    executor.executeAsync({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/$batch",
        method: "POST",
        body: batchBody,
        headers: {
            "X-RequestDigest": document.getElementById("__REQUESTDIGEST").value,
            "Content-Type": "multipart/mixed; boundary=batch_" + batchGuid
        },
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            var responseInLines = response.body.toString().split('\n');
            // read routine below courtesy of Andrew Connell: https://github.com/andrewconnell/sp-o365-rest/tree/master/SpRestBatchSample
            // read each line until you find JSON...
            for (var currentLine = 0; currentLine < responseInLines.length; currentLine++) {
                try {
                    // parse the JSON response...
                    var tryParseJson = JSON.parse(responseInLines[currentLine]);
                    console.log(tryParseJson.d.results);
                } catch (e) {
                    // don't do anything... just keep moving

                    // execution in this block just means we hit a 
                    // line in the response that was not valid JSON -JM
                }
            }
        },
        error: function (response) { console.log(response) }
    });
});
```

Reference - [SPRestBatchsample](https://github.com/andrewconnell/sp-o365-rest/tree/master/SpRestBatchSample)

[Basic batched request using REST](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/166010/basic-batched-get-requests-using-rest-api)

[Datajs](https://datajs.codeplex.com/)

You can also us the datajs library to batch calls as below:

```
var jsonSPHeaders = {  
    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose", 
    "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "DataServiceVersion": "3.0" 
};

OData.request( {
    requestUri: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/$batch",
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
               "DataServiceVersion": "3.0" },
    data: { __batchRequests: [
       { requestUri: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/emails24/1001')/Files", method: "GET" , headers: jsonSPHeaders },
       { requestUri: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/scaned/1001')/Files", method: "GET" , headers: jsonSPHeaders },
       { requestUri: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/lnked/1001')/Files", method: "GET", headers: jsonSPHeaders }
    ]}
},
function (data, response) {
    console.log('First data:');
    printListItems(data.__batchResponses[0].data);
    console.log('Second data:');
    printListItems(data.__batchResponses[1].data);
    console.log('Third data:');
    printListItems(data.__batchResponses[2].data);
}, 
null, 
OData.batchHandler);

function printListItems(data){
   data.results.forEach(function(item){
       console.log(item); 
   });
}
```

Comment: Great :) how would one achieve sorting and paging?

Comment: you can use `$orderby` to sort that data based on the field. To use paging, you can use `$skip` or `$skiptoken=Paged=TRUE&p_ID=1`.
Check this link - [SharePoint paging](http://www.dev4side.com/en/blog/posts/2014/04/10/list-elements-pagination-with-sharepoint-2013-rest-api-%E2%80%93-part-1)

Comment: got 404, when executing batch request - mysite/module/_api/$batch

Comment: is it SharePoint 2013 On prem environment ?

Comment: Yes, sharepoint 2013 on premises

Comment: @pirabdulwakeel - sorry you are out of luck :( , `$batch`  is only supported in Office 365 and SharePoint 2016. You need to use old school `listdata.svc/$batch` methods.

Comment: but you know, I am fetching something other than list, want to fetch files and folders, and in that case listdata.svc won't help me.