# How to create multiple columns in a SP list using single REST call

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, spfx, spfx-webparts

I want to create 3 columns in a SP list from my SPFX webpart using REST call. Could you please let me know how to achieve this? I am using below code to create 1 column but instead I want create 3 different columns using single REST call.

```
url: https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('MyList')/fields
    const response = await fetch(url, {
       method: 'POST',
       credentilas: 'include',
       headers: {
           Accept: 'application/json;odata=verbose',
           'Content-Type': 'application/json;odata=nometadadat',
           'x-RequestDigest': xRequestDigestValue
       },
       body: JSON.stringyfy({
          Required: true,
          FiledTypeKind: 6,
          Title: 'MyChoice'
       })
    }
```

Comment: Are you asking how to create 3 columns with a single call?

Comment: Yes, 3 columns in a single call. You are correct.

Comment: I guess you can make batch requests with the REST APIs for such requirements. Check for it.

Comment: @GaneshSanap could you please provide me some links for batch requests. I am new to this. Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you want/need to create all three with a _single_ call?  If you manage your async requests/Promises correctly, you can make 3 parallel (but individual) calls, and still delay subsequent code execution until all 3 are finished.

Comment: @DylanCristy what I understand one single http request is always better than multiple requests. But always welcome to correct me if there are cons. Wanted to use only for better performance.

Comment: In a very general sense, yes, fewer calls are better, however there are times when you just can't do what you want with a single request.  :)  Also, though, 1 vs. 3 is less important to try and optimize than 1 vs. 20.  In this case (creating fields), I do not know for sure that you _can't_ do what you want with a batch request, I would research that as Ganesh has suggested if you _really_ want to try to get it done in a single call.  But personally - 1 vs. 3 is not enough of an optimization for me to spend my time trying to figure out a batch call when I can just get it done. But that's me. :)

Comment: @DylanCristy Thank you for your reply. I understand :)

Comment: @sarbashis, Check [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/make-batch-requests-with-the-rest-apis), [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sharepoint-batch-request-for-add-list-item/) and [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/166010/basic-batched-get-requests-using-rest-api) for Batch requests references.

Comment: As @DylanCristy suggested, if you want to create **only** 3 columns then using 3 parallel REST calls and pushing them to single promise object, you can resolve them in `promise.all()`. You can write your other business logic you want to perform after field creation in `promise.all()`. But, if you want make large number of REST calls and optimize the performance then you can explore more on batch requests.

Comment: Thanks @GaneshSanap. It means a lot. :)

Comment: You're welcome @sarbashis

Comment: @GaneshSanap could you please help me in one my question which I have posted. https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/285673/how-to-create-a-managed-metadata-column-in-sp-list-using-rest-api-in-spfx-webpar

I am struggling on that. Trying to find out but could not. I will edit the question with my latest try